# Extract elements from XML in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to pull nested XML elements and turn it into a table result in SQL. A WorkItem always has a group, but Group fields can be nested N times. Is there an easy way to pull JUST the Fields out of an XML field that looks like this:

```
declare @xml XML = '
<WorkItem>
  <Group Name="Base" >
    <Field FieldId="361" Name="Assigned To"  />
    <Field FieldId="362" Name="Stuff"  />
    <Group Name="Detail">
      <Field FieldId="363" Name="Assigned To 2" />
    </Group>
  </Group>
</WorkItem>'

declare @handle int
declare @status int

exec @status = sp_xml_preparedocument @handle output, @xml
select *
from openxml(@handle, 'WorkItem/Group/Field')
with (
    FieldId int,
    Name varchar(max)
)
exec sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

What I'm getting:

```
361,Assigned To
362,Stuff
```

What I'm expecting:

```
361,Assigned To
362,Stuff
363,Assigned To 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: I copied and pasted your sample to rextester (+1 for a ready-to-use sample data), [but I can't reproduce the problem.](http://rextester.com/DRNX91743)

Comment: Btw: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's better to use [XQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server):

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<WorkItem>
  <Group Name="Base" >
    <Field FieldId="361" Name="Assigned To"  />
    <Field FieldId="362" Name="Stuff"  />
    <Group Name="Detail">
      <Field FieldId="363" Name="Assigned To 2" />
    </Group>
  </Group>
</WorkItem>';


SELECT 
    n.value('@FieldId', 'int') FieldId, 
    n.value('@Name', 'varchar(250)') Name
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/WorkItem//Field') xml(n);
```

Output:

```
FieldId     Name
----------- --------------------
361         Assigned To
362         Stuff
363         Assigned To 2
```

Comment: This works, however I cut and pasted wrong in my XML. The Group elements should have been nested.

Comment: @DanChampagne, ok. I have edited my answer. Check it.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! It worked perfectly :)

Comment: @DanChampagne, glad to help you :)